# How to perform single imputation of a categorical variable in SPSS?

Tags: spss, missing-data

My supervisor is convinced that the following procedure for single imputation of missing values of a categorical variable can be performed in SPSS: missing observations for that variable are RANDOMLY assigned the variable categories (levels) in the same distribution in which they occur in the non-missing observations.

So, a dumb example: I have a binary variable (say, gender) in 8 observations; the variable is not missing in 6 observations, and it is 0=male in 3 (50%) and 1=female in 3 (50%); the procedure would randomly assign to the remaining 2 observations, in which it is missing, the gender 0=male to one and 1=female to the other one, so that the distribution is still 50%-50%. The dataset would be created by

```
data list free/gender.
begin data
0 1 0 1 0 1 '' ''
end data.
```

I can perform the procedure in R, where you are free to manipulate vectors and the like. But after days of studying and surfing the web, I cannot do it in SPSS. There are only built-in single imputation methods such as the Expectation-Maximization method, and I cannot easily do it manually. 
Not that I do not believe the method can be fully maximized. Assume there was one more missing observation in my example dataset: you would have 3 missing observations, so you would be forced to have 33.3% of one gender and 66.6%^of the other gender. In most cases, you won't be able to reproduce the exact same distribution of levels as in the non-missing observations. This last choice must be done by a human.

How would you do it? Is my supervisor wrong?

Important note: this is about the procedure, not the validity of this incredibly rough imputation method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some replacement functions for missing data in the menu under "Transform -> Replace Missing Values".

The transformation you are looking for, I think, is possible with a little trick.

Now lets make use of the "series mean" method from the Replace Missing Values function.

```
RMV /gender_1=SMEAN(gender).
```

Because the gender variable is 0-1 coded, this procedure returns the proportion of 1 compared to 0, where gender is missing and saves it into the variable gender_1. Where gender is not missing the value of gender is returned. The proportion value can also be viewed as the probability that gender will have the value 1. Now you can replace them with bernoulli distributed random numbers (using the probability stored in "gender_1").

```
* Where gender is missing, replace the value for the "probability" of gender=1 
* with a bernoulli distributed random number (0 or 1) given this probability.
DO IF MISSING(gender).
   COMPUTE gender_1 = RV.BERNOULLI(gender_1).
END IF.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: Effective, and elegant as well. Thank you!